# Cant make profile2 fields visible to other users

Tags: users

How can you make a profile (from the profile2 module) visible to all visitors?

I've given all users permission to "View user profiles". When viewing a user's page the fields from core are visible (username and picture). However the fields I've added with the profile2 module are not visible.

The profile2 fields are only visible when a user looks at their own profile, or when the administrator views users profiles. This seems like a permissions issue but I cant see what permission to change.

Comment: in case it helps https://drupal.org/node/1074296

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profile2 module separates core drupal user profile by adding a separate profile entity to it.The permission "view user profile" you are adding is related to drupal core user management not with profile 2 module.

Here is a screenshot for working permission set for a profile created using profile2 mdoule. The profile name is common

[image]

The roles in the screen shot are anonymous, authenticated administrator cutom_role.

As a tutorial this [video](http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/drupal-7-profile-2-module) can help.